# Modeling an arched roof/ceiling

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, geometry

I am making an arched ceiling that has a unique shape, the bottoms/corners are angular but the actual ceiling is rounded.

How to get the shape correct? I'm currently using a subdivision modifier but there is an odd area where the mesh is piling up that causes a "pinch".

Also, the ceiling will have arches so the window needs to match the arches, Ive included the concept art as well as what I've done so far.

[image]
[image]
[image]